# matplotlib installed but not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, windows-10

I've read other questions about this but none seems help.
I have matplotlib installed:

```
C:\Users\johns\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.10>pip show matplotlib
Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.6.0
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: c:\users\johns\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
Requires: contourpy, cycler, fonttools, kiwisolver, numpy, packaging, pillow, pyparsing, python-dateutil
Required-by:
```

yet when I try to use it:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

or

```
import matplotlib
```

it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\johns\OneDrive\Desktop\Università\TESI\Main.py", line 2, in <module>
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\johns\OneDrive\Desktop\Università\TESI\Main.py", line 2, in <module>
import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: Wich version of Python are you currently using?

Comment: python version is 3.10

Comment: Ok, I re-installed with `py -m pip install matplotlib` and now it works, thank you.